# Block is not calling in magento2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I am trying to print hello world using block and phtml file. here is my code,
app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Display.php

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
  {
      parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function sayHello()
  {
      return __('Hello World');
  }
}
```

app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Display.php

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
protected $_pageFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Display" name="helloworld_display" template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::sayhello.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

view/frontend/templates/sayHello.phtml

```
<?php

 /**
 * @var \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Display $block
 */

echo $block->sayHello();
```

etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
        <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share `routes.xml` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mistake in your controller class namespace.

Replace

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Controller\Index;
```

with

```
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;
```